# Multi-line highlighting in Sublime Text syntax definition

Tags: regex, xml, syntax, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I'm trying to create a syntax highlighter that matches custom headers in my logs.  Here's an example:

```
SYSTEM INFORMATION
Memory
----------------------------------------
Total                    14841733120
Free                     12260917248
Active                   583532544
Swap Total               5009104896
Swap Free                5009104896
% Used                   3
% Swap Used              0

Disk
----------------------------------------
Total                    114272681984
Free                     107483385856
% Used                   5
```

What I want to match is the header line (eg, Memory) and the following line's dashes.  I've developed a regex pattern to do just this:

```
^[\w|\ ]+(\ {0,})\n(\-{40})
```

Unfortunately, when I try to create a custom syntax highlighter, this regex no longer matches.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>mylog</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>section header</string>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>^[\w|\ ]+(\ {0,})\n(\-{40})</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>constant.character.mylog</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>text.mylog</string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>unique-uuid</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any suggestions on getting the custom syntax highlighter to match both lines?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it just isn't possible. See the [TextMate Manual](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#rule_keys). You can't use a single regex to match across lines. The closest thing you can do is probably use the `begin` and `end` keywords. See if this is to your liking?

```
...
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>begin</key>
        <string>^[A-Z][a-z ]*$</string>
        <key>end</key>
        <string>-{40}</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>variable.parameter</string>
    </dict>
</array>
...
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it was close enough that I can work with it.  I hadn't considered the begin and end constructs -- those are the most useful part.  Thanks for the suggestion!